# Where does windows 10 download its update files to

Tags: windows-10, automatic-update

I have automatic updates turned on in windows 10. So I presume windows 10 automatically downloads and installs these updates for me. My questions are as follows:

- Where (which directory) do these files get downloaded to?
- Is it safe to delete these files to reclaim disk space?

Answer (score 4):

Of course you have automatic updates enabled. There is no Control Panel option to disable them starting from Windows 10. As far as I know Windows downloads updates to:

```
C:/Windows/SoftwareDistribution/Download
```

After installing updates, reboot when prompted and you can delete those files.

Comment: Not completely correct. Windows won’t download updates on connections you mark as “metered.” And Windows 10 Professional allows feature updates to be delayed for several months ("Defer upgrades”).

Answer (score -1):

Since MS has made all Windows 10 updates go through MS-Store, instead of an actual website, you could take the following steps:

1. in search field type GPO (and go to the group policy editor)
2. then go to the following sections:
   computer config->admin templates->windows components->windows update
3. Scroll about mid-way, and double click "do not connect to any windows update locations" and then enable.

Warning: if this does work the way it should it could make your MS-Store not work, and will block any MS Update.

Comment: “Since MS has made all updates to go through MS-Store,” - This is false....